# Codeblocks compilation not executable

Tags: c++, c, windows, codeblocks

I'm trying to compile the following code using Codebloks Nightly svn 9916

```
#include "Main.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running the executable from inside Codeblocks, it returns `Hello World!` as expected to. But if the executable is started from outside it returns an application error `0xc000007b`. It means that either the System type (32bit or 64bit) doesn't fit, or that the executable is broken. But I don't understand why the the compilation is fine while executing from Codeblocks.
The executable itself is 32bit (x86) and running it from a 32bit or 64bit cmd doesn't make a change.

Data:
Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit
GNU GCC Compiler

***EDIT: Workarround***

Statically linking the c++ library against the executable works. It seems like windows can't execute it if the c++ standard library isn't available.

Comment: You probably need one or more of the gcc dll files in your path or in the directory where the executable is.  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can be helpful to see what's missing.

Comment: Main.h is just a blank autogenerated header

Comment: @Matze: When you found the solution, post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statically linking the C++ default library works.

Just add `-static-libstdc++` to your linking statement

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up your compiler again from statch to see if that is causing the issue, I would recommend watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVmd0P85D8o) at it pretty much describes how to do it from step 1.